# How do I do the type-hint 'automatic injection' custom class laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, type-hinting

Below is the EmailNotifier Class

```
class EmailNotifier 
{
    public function notify()
    {
        echo 'Sending payment notification via email' ;
    }
}
```

Below is my AppServiceProvider

```
 class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {

        public function boot()
        {

        }

        public function register()
        {
           $this->app->make(App\EmailNotifier::class); // resolve the EmailNotifier Class
        }

    }
```

Below is billing class

```
class Billing
{

     protected $notifier;


     public function __construct(EmailNotifier  $notifier)
     {
         $this->notifier = $notifier;
     }

     public function pay()
     {
        // Process the bill payment
         $this->notifier->notify();
     }

}
```

and in my controller I did

```
  $data = new Billing(1);
```

As you can see I already resolve the EmailNotifier Class at the AppServiceProvider Class but when I call that like the code above, it throws an error said 'must be an instance of EmailNotifier'

and based on the laravel documentation, it's stated that :

> you may "type-hint" the dependency in the constructor of a class that
>   is resolved by the container (for the [automatic injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#automatic-injection))

how do I achieve automatic injection for the type-hint in laravel ?

Comment: add folder name of emailnotifier on composer autoload

Comment: @Sohel0415 autoload is done but still not functioning

Comment: remove 1 from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$data = resolve(Billing::class);` instead of `$data = new Billing(1);` and you can remove `$this->app->make(App\EmailNotifier::class); // resolve the EmailNotifier Class` from service provider's register method.